# How to gulp a task without "primordials is not defined" and "Assertion error" errors

Tags: gulp, task, tomcat8

Today I tried to gulp a task inside my web application project folder on Tomcat8. I got a source code for a web app and I am trying to customize it.

I know there are several explanations about the errors I am going to show you, but it's always about switching from V3.9.1 to V4.0.2 and from V4.0.2 to V3.9.1 my gulp version. And I get a different problem on both :D

**V3.9.1 Gulp:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master>gulp
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master>gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 3.9.1
```

**V4.0.2 Gulp**

```
    AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\gulpfile.js:18:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at execute (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

**Task script**

I was also wondering why in my task scripts there is no task name … I would like to try my commands with a task name after "gulp". When I check on other task files there is always a task name:

```
'use strict';
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    war = require('gulp-war'),
    zip = require('gulp-zip'),`enter code here`
    path = require('path');
module.exports = function (gulp) {
    return function () {
        return gulp.src('dist/bundled/**')
            .pipe(war({
                welcome: 'index.html',
                displayName: 'downtime-app',
            }))
            .pipe(zip('downtime-app.war'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
    };
};
```

Sorry if I am saying any blunders, I am a total beginner and didn't even know what was HTML 1 week ago … :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gulp 3.*.* and node 12+ => it will give the error.

Uninstall it and use node 11.*.* with gulp 3.*.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I replace all my tasks by a single and basic one, the gulp 4.0.2V works well:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Source code test\Source code test\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master>gulp bacon
[14:46:12] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Source code test\Source code test\Source code for Apache\pa-downtime-uApp-master\gulpfile.js
[14:46:12] Starting 'bacon'...
miam miam
[14:46:12] The following tasks did not complete: bacon
[14:46:12] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

So I think the problem remains in the dependencies between the several tasks or, in the bonds between the gulpfile.js and the task folder that was made by my web application creator.
Finally I found the task names in the gulpfile.js but even using them doesn't work.